# logo not show on right position in checkout page in magento2

Tags: magento2

**Below is my checkout page file codec :**

```
<referenceBlock name="header.wrapper" remove="false"/>
<referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
<referenceBlock name="header.panel" remove="false" />
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
<referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>
```

Comment: Could you pass the site URL , where it showing or share the screenshots

Comment: apetrailportfolio.com/magemod/

Comment: logo is not coming there, display logo first then I ll help you in positioning

Comment: check this i add sir

Comment: you need to adjust your CSS , like you have given ".block-search{float:left !important;}" removing important will work for you...adjust the rest of css

Comment: Place your logo before minicart-wrapper in XML file , using before after

Comment: can u   tell me which right snippad for it using code thanks in advance

Comment: add code in your extended checkout_cart_index.xml